# Pass list of different titles, contents and other details via intent in Android

Tags: android, arrays, list, android-intent

Newbie android/java dev here. How can I pass custom lists via intent with loop?

The problem is the list of "Restaurants" is displayed in the firstactivity.

A "Details/Menu" button under the restaurant name will be clicked and I want to display the "Food Menu" and other relevant information of that specific restaurant via array.

It should be passed from firstactivity to the secondactivity with a loop (I think), so that it will use just few textviews.

The button should pass these data according to the Restaurant clicked.

- Name of the Restaurant
- URL of the restaurant drawable profile photo
- URL of the restaurant drawable cover photo
- The Title of the Food Category (*PROBLEM)
- The lists of food in that specific category and its price (*PROBLEM)

My question is, how to pass the data automatically and how to make this code better and short? Thank you so much for the help!

Here is the sample of firstactivity.

[First Activity Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CuJpW.png)

Here is the java code of First Activity:

```
    public void bluecafedetails (View dineview) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(DineActivity.this, DineDetailsActivity.class);
    String TitleofDine = "Blue Cafe";
    String AddressofDine = "2nd Floor, VTC, Gogon, Virac, Catanduanes";
    String OpenHoursofDine = "8AM - 10PM / Everyday";
    String DineDelivery = "Yes";
    String MenuTitle = "All Day Breakfast";
    intent.putExtra("DineTitle", TitleofDine);
    intent.putExtra("DineAddress", AddressofDine);
    intent.putExtra("DineOpenHours", OpenHoursofDine);
    intent.putExtra("DineDelivery", DineDelivery);
    intent.putExtra("MenuTitle", MenuTitle);
    intent.putExtra("image",R.drawable.blue_cafe_logo);
    this.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Here is the sample of secondactivity.
[Second Activity Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/seaQK.png)

Here is the java code in the second activity so far:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dine_details);

    TextView dineTitle = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dinetitle);
    TextView dineAddress = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dineaddress);
    TextView dineDelivery = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.acceptsdeliveryanswer);
    TextView dineOpenHours = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.openhours);
    TextView dineMenuTitle = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.menutitle);

    Intent anotherActivityIntent = getIntent();

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();


    String DineTitle= anotherActivityIntent.getStringExtra("DineTitle");
    String DineAddress= anotherActivityIntent.getStringExtra("DineAddress");
    String DineOpenHours= anotherActivityIntent.getStringExtra("DineOpenHours");
    String DineDelivery= anotherActivityIntent.getStringExtra("DineDelivery");
    String MenuTitle= anotherActivityIntent.getStringExtra("MenuTitle");
    int imageId = getIntent().getIntExtra("image", 0);

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.dinelogo);
    imageView.setImageResource(imageId);

    dineTitle.setText(DineTitle);
    dineAddress.setText(DineAddress);
    dineDelivery.setText(DineDelivery);
    dineOpenHours.setText(DineOpenHours);
    dineMenuTitle.setText(MenuTitle);
    this.setTitle(DineTitle);
```

Comment: Use parcalable class object to pass bulk data.

Comment: Hi @Nas! thanks for the reply, I checked the parcelable and I think that's what I need but,

1.) How can I display the bulk result I passed from the first activity to my layout xml of the second activity?
E.g.
"All day breakfast"
should fall under the Textview ID (food_category) 

and the food items that is under "All day breakfast" will fall under textview ID (food_items)

and it should loop as long as I have lots of category and their food items declared on first act.

2.) Can you place a sample code how it should be done so it will be clear for me and for others. Thanks.

Comment: can u share your custom list class